# how update sql table with variable

Tags: python, html, sql

```
def changePassword():
with sqlite3.connect('RealTime.db') as conn: // <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x7ff18eef1a80>
    cur = conn.cursor() //<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7ff18ef08420>
    result = request.form
    username = RES['user'] //'RJV@gmail.com'
    t = (username,) //('RJV@gmail.com',)
    user = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME=? ", t).fetchone() //('RJV@gmail.com', 'Roni', '1258')
    if(result.get('oldPass') == newDic(user)['password']):
        newPass = result.get('newPass') //'1234'
        try:
            cur.execute("UPDATE users SET password = newPass WHERE username = username")
            conn.commit()
            return redirect('/')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return render_template('RealTimeChangePassword.html')
    return render_template('RealTimeChangePassword.html')
```

hey i try to update my password in users with variable newPass
so i try to sent the newPass to username 'RJV@gmail.com'
but i dont know why its fall

but when i do like this:

> cur.execute("UPDATE users SET password = 1234 WHERE username =
> 'RJV@gmail.com' ")

its update...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change the line where you set the password to something like this:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE username = ?", (username, password))
```

Before you were changing the password of a user litterally called username and not one called e.g. RJV@gmail.com

Comment: Throws an exception that he can only get two arguments and not 3
And if I mark everything in parentheses he says he can not get a tuple

Comment: Updated it according to the specification. Please try again :D

Comment: Great but i jut need to replace to this and its work (password,username) !! thankyou